# Duvídas Search query com tabela

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Estou criando uma caixa de pesquisa que permite aos utilizadores do meu sistema pesquisar produtos inseridos na base de dados consoante o seu nome e ano de inserção (por enquanto), o código desenvolvido até ao momento já retorna os todos os valores inseridos na base de dados se não for efectuada uma pesquisa e retorna o valor pesquisado, mas isso apenas acontece com um echo $data['nome'] independente, e quando tentei implementar isso nas tabelas não apresenta nenhum output, a minha ideia seria que fosse possível ao utilizador ver todos os registos que estão inseridos na base dados quando não pretende efectuar a pesquisa mas que quando efectuasse uma pesquisa esses mesmos dados dados fossem filtrados de maneira a apresentar apenas o que foi pesquisado.

**Actualmente isto é o que me aparece:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código HTML (Caixa de pesquisa):**

```
 <form method="post" action="index.php">
                            <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Pesquise um produto...">
                            <select name="column">
                                <option value="">Selecionar</option>
                                <option value="nome">Produtos</option>
                                <option value="ano_atual">Produtos P/Ano</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pesquisar">
                        </form>
```

**Código PHP (Resultado da pesquisa /Tabela):**

```
<?php
    require_once "config.php";                    

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "pap_database");
        $q = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['q']);
        $column = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['column']);

        if ($column == "" || ($column != "nome" && $column != "ano_atual"))
            $column = "nome";

        $sql = $connection->query("SELECT nome,preco_base,iva,stock,preco_com_iva FROM produtos WHERE $column LIKE '%$q%'");

            while ($data = $sql->fetch_array())

                            echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
                                echo "<thead>"; 
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<th>Produto</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Preço Base (€)</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Stock (Unidades)</th>";
                                        echo "<th>IVA</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Preço c/IVA (€)</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Opções</th>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                echo "</thead>";
                                echo "<tbody>";

                                    echo "<tr>";

                                        echo "<td>" . $data['nome'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $data['preco_base'] . "€</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $data['stock'] . " Unidades</td>"; 
                                        echo "<td>" . $data['iva'] . "%</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $data['preco_com_iva'] . "€</td>";
                                        echo "<td>";
                                            echo "<a href='read.php?id=". $data['idprodutos'] ."' title='View Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='fa fa-eye-open'></span></a>";
                                            echo "<a href='update.php?id=". $data['idprodutos'] ."' title='Update Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='fa fa-pencil'></span></a>";
                                            echo "<a href='delete.php?id=". $data['idprodutos'] ."' title='Delete Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='fa fa-trash'></span></a>";
                                        echo "</td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                }
                         else{
            echo "A pesquisa efetuada não devolve nenhum registo!";
    }

                                echo "</tbody>";                            
                            echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: UniX, por que você não tira a cláusula where se a variável `q` for vazia?

Comment: Como assim? @Lucas?

Comment: Com o código como está agora, se não definir nada na pesquisa que informação é devolvida? Não devolve todos os registos?

Comment: @João Martins, com o código que tenho agora se eu não pesquisar nada não mostra nada, se pesquisar também não mostra nada.

Comment: @JoãoMartins mas já verifiquei com um echo independente (sem a tabela etc) e ele mostra os dados que estão na db consoante a pesquisa

Comment: Se retirar a cláusula `WHERE` da sua consulta, o que devolve?

Comment: Você pode fazer um debug do que você está recebendo para entender melhor o seu próprio código, primeiro adicione print_r() as variáveis $q e $column, crie um variável $query e coloque ela recebendo seu sql montado! ex: $query = "SELECT nome,preco_base,iva,stock,preco_com_iva FROM produtos WHERE $column LIKE '%$q%'"; e de um print_r nele tbm. depois execute $sql = $connection->query($query);, assim você irá visualizar cada passo para melhor identificar o erro.

Comment: @MarcusItalo vou experimentar

Comment: @JoãoMartins se tirar (Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\administracao\produtos\index.php:180 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\administracao\produtos\index.php on line 180)

Comment: O que acho que o @JoãoMartins quis dizer é o seguinte:
            $where = (($column != ""))?WHERE $column LIKE '%$q%':'';
        $sql = $connection->query("SELECT nome,preco_base,iva,stock,preco_com_iva FROM produtos $where "); em substituição da linha:
if ($column == "" || ($column != "nome" && $column != "ano_atual"))
            $column = "nome";

        $sql = $connection->query("SELECT nome,preco_base,iva,stock,preco_com_iva FROM produtos WHERE $column LIKE '%$q%'");

Comment: O que queria dizer era colocar a seguinte consulta: `SELECT nome,preco_base,iva,stock,preco_com_iva FROM produtos`.

Comment: @JoãoMartins acabei de experimentar o SELECT e não retorna nada